# O que leva um código a ter diferentes representações visuais em navegadores diferentes?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Eu tenho um site que estou desenvolvendo no qual tenho um menu superior fixo (um navbar). O problema é essa navbar tem diferentes visualizações no Chrome e no Firefox. Gostaria de saber o porquê disso acontecer.

- Utilizo Bootstrap 4.3.1 na página.

**Veja abaixo o código da navbar:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Estilo customizado -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">


  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top navbar-transparente">

      <div class="container">

        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand text-light" id="a-logo">
          <marquee>Thiago Petherson | Desenvolvedor Web</marquee>
        </a>



        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal">
     <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
    </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/cursos.html" class="nav-link">Minhas Qualificações</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/calculador_imc.php" class="nav-link">Calcule seu IMC</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item divisor">

            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/consideracoes.html" class="nav-link">Me conheça</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-link">Projetos Desenvolvidos</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/historico-profissional.html" class="nav-link">Histórico Profissional</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Fim do Cabeçalho -->
```

**Como fica no Chrome:**

[image: **Como fica no Chrome:**]

**Agora no Firefox**

[image: **Agora no Firefox**]

Gostaria de saber o motivo disso acontecer e se tem como resolver. Essas coisas acontecem muito em navegadores diferentes. Já passei por diversas situações em que o código era exibido de forma diferentes nos navegadores. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Bootstrap 4 é baseado em HTML5 e o `marquee` é obsoleto. Embora ele até funcione, não é recomendado usá-lo pois pode ser removido a qualquer hora dos navegadores.

Com isso, o Firefox junto com o sistema de grid do BS4 está tratando a tag de forma diferente em relação ao Chrome (e de outros navegadores, como IE11 e Edge), não se ajustando dentro do flexbox, esticando a largura da tag, fazendo com ele ocupe mais espaço do que deveria dentro do flexbox.

Esqueça o `marquee` e use uma animação moderna com `@keyframes`. O efeito é o mesmo e é compatível com HTML5.

Troque o `<marquee>` por um `<span>` e insira este CSS abaixo para fazer a animação:

```
#a-logo{
   overflow: hidden;
}

#a-logo span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

O valor `15s` (15 segundos) na propriedade `animation` é o tempo que o texto irá levar para cruzar de uma ponta a outra. Esse tempo você pode ajustar como quiser.

**Veja um exemplo:**

```css
body{
 background: blue !important;
}

.nav-item a{
   white-space: nowrap !important;
}

#a-logo{
   overflow: hidden;
}

#a-logo span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top navbar-transparente">

      <div class="container">

      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand text-light" id="a-logo">
         <span>Thiago Petherson | Desenvolvedor Web</span>
      </a>



        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-principal">
     <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
    </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-principal">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/cursos.html" class="nav-link">Minhas Qualificações</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/calculador_imc.php" class="nav-link">Calcule seu IMC</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item divisor">

            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/consideracoes.html" class="nav-link">Me conheça</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="" class="nav-link">Projetos Desenvolvidos</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="views/historico-profissional.html" class="nav-link">Histórico Profissional</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Mas Sam, será que é só o marque que está estragando todos os outros elementos que estão na navbar ? Pois se vc parar  o problema que está acontecendo não se baseia na funcionalidade do marque, e sim dos <li>...

Comment: É o marquee mesmo que está quebrando o layout. O Firefox não está tratando ele como o Chrome trata, por exemplo.

Comment: O que é esse @keyframes ?

Comment: É uma animação CSS.

Comment: Fiz sua sugestão mas o texto do <span> fica parado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no exemplo que postei, não fica parado :D

Comment: Quer dizer, verifiquei aqui agora. O que estava acontecendo no firefox, agora está acontecendo no Chrome. No Firefox deu certo.

Comment: Não percebi aqui não. Coloquei `.nav-item a{
   white-space: nowrap !important;
}` para não quebrar linhas no menu.

Comment: Com isso resolveu, @Sam. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

## Problema

Existem alguns regras pre definidas nos navegadores, o tamanho de borda, de espaçamento e por ai vai, uma boa solução é "resetar" estas regras antes de começa a codificar.

## Solução

Você pode normalizar estas regras, já existe isso pronto para baixar, você consegue baixar o css [aqui](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

## Como usar

É só baixar o `normalize.css` e colocar antes das suas regras, assim ele ira normalizar todas regras, evitando assim divergências.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
```

## Extra

Outra solução é resetar as regras, "zerando" cada atributo, abaixo alguns links com exemplos.

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6